# ngAfterViewChecked is stuck on a loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>` to start from the bottom, it works, but I can't seem to scroll up

I think it's because of the `AfterViewChecked`, I tried `AfterViewInit` and it doesn't seem to work.

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport, { static: false }) viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this.viewport.scrollTo({ bottom: 0 });
}
```

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="70">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let message of messages">
    {{message}}
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

How can I scroll up again? Or just execute `AfterViewChecked` once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AfterViewChecked will cause list to scroll down every time a view change has been completed.

You can try using ViewChild setter it will be called only when the child is ready.

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport, { static: false }) 
set viewport(viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport) {
   viewport.scrollTo({ bottom: 0 });
}
```

Comment: It seems that issue is that this component has to keep rendering, therefore  triggering setter. 

Would it work if you tried? I've tried it on stack blitz and it worked.

ngAfterViewInit() {
     setTimeout(() => viewport.scrollTo({ bottom: 0 }));
}

Something like this will work but it looks really bad.

  loaded = false;

  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport, { static: false }) 
  set viewport(viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport) {
    if (!this.loaded) {
      viewport.scrollTo({ bottom: 0 });
      this.loaded = !!viewport.getRenderedRange().end;
    }
  }

Comment: Component will first render without children that is why ngAfterViewInit doesn't work. Adding timeout will trigger scrolling after children have been rendered.

Comment: `loaded = false; @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport, { static: false }) set viewport(viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport) { if (!this.loaded) { viewport.scrollTo({ bottom: 0 }); this.loaded = !!viewport.getRenderedRange().end; } }` works! thank you